# Which Sampradayas follow which Dharamshastras?

Tags: dharma-shastras, sects, sampradaya

As I understand, the texts followed by devotees depend for the most part on which Sampradaya they are a part of. For example, people in the Nandinatha Sampradaya give more importance to the Shiv Puran than someone in the Sri Vaishnava Sampradaya. Which Dharmashastras would each of the Sampradayas follow? In addition, which dharmashastras would the shrauta and surya sampradayas follow?

Comment: Your question is too broad.Edit and mention some specific Sampradayas about which you would like to know more initially....

Comment: Surya and shrauta please